# Здравствуйте! Помогите пож по задаче js:

Tags: javascript

Такая задача: "Верните длину самой длинной подстроки из повторяющихся символов из функции repeatSub без учета регистра. Если строка пустая то вернуть "0".
Не могу вернуть "0".
Вот моё решение:

```
function repeatSub(str){
var result = {};
str=str.toLowerCase().split('').sort();
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){   
    var a = str[i];
    if (result[a] != undefined)
        result[a]+=1;
    else
        result[a] = 1;
}
result=Object.values(result);
if(result == ""){return 0};
let max = Math.max(...result);
return max;
}
```

Comment: 1. У вас result это массив чисел, он не может быть равен пустой строке. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно в самом начале сравнить str с пустой строкой, и если равно, вернуть ноль. 2. Алгоритм у вас не совсем верный: вы разбиваете строку на символы и сортируете их. В таком случае вы уже ищете не самую длинную подстроку из повторов, расположенных подряд, а самое большое количество одинаковых символов в строке независимо от положения. Например, по условиям в строке 'аабббаа' самая длинная подстрока — это ббб, а у вас получится, что самое большое количество одинаковых символов — это четыре буквы 'а'.

Comment: vsemozhebuty, спасибо